# redirect in react-router undefined?

Tags: react-router

This is what my react-router code looks like

```
render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path={CORP} component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path={"outreach"} component={OutReach}/>
      <Route path={"careers/m"} component={Career}/>
      <Route path={"members"} component={Members}/>
      <Redirect from="*" to={"/home"} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

But when I go to my page, I get this error in my console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Redirect is not defined

How do I tell react-router to redirect the user to the `/home` only when the user's destination does not match any of the route paths mentioned above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to add

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
```

In the top of your file